# sed error "Invalid range end"

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed, substitution

I run this substitution command on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ sed -e "s/([a-zA-Z0-9.-/\\ :]+)/\1/g"
```

However, the following error is raised.

> sed: -e expression #1, char 27: Invalid range end

I can remember the same expression works on MacOSX.
Can you describe why the command fails?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can solve it in two ways. One of them is to use `-r` switch to avoid escaping special characters and move `-` in the range to first or last position and avoid its special meaning, it would be like:

```
sed -re "s/([a-zA-Z0-9./\\ :-]+)/\1/g"
```

Otherwise you will need to escape either `(`, `)` and `+`, like:

```
sed -e "s/\([a-zA-Z0-9./\\ :-]\+\)/\1/g"
```

Comment: Thx! It works on the command line. Though, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637799/sed-error-invalid-reference-1-on-s-commands-rhs) is a follow up question.