# Sed Invalid range end error with captured group

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to run the following bash program with sed and I am seeing an sed: -e expression #1, char 44: Invalid range end
. I [tried adding the -r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637432/sed-error-invalid-range-end) option but still seeing the error.

```
#!/bin/bash


TEST="--extra-vars user=jsmith a=abcd --test"

echo $TEST | sed -re "s/(--extra-vars )([a-zA-z0-9\=\s]*)\b/\1\2/g"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting an `Invalid range end` error because you've wrote `A-z` inside your character class, which is a negative range (`z` < `A`).